# how to stringify a value if im using ember power select

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

im using Ember Power Select to have users fill out a form. One of the select options may have two values. I need to take that value and turn it into a string to send to the backend.

Is there a way to do this on the template side?

```
      {{#power-select-multiple
        options=names
        selected=experiment.owners 
        placeholder="Add owners"
        onchange=(action (mut experiment.owners))
        as |name|
      }}
        {{name}}
      {{/power-select-multiple}}
```

In the option below:

```
        selected=experiment.owners
```

If the user add two people like "Bob, Michael", it will come back in an array. I would like to make this into a string.

I would like for it to return something like:

```
"Bob, Michael"
```

Instead of

```
[Bob, Michael]
```

Comment: you could do: `{{#each experiment.owners as |owner|}}{{owner}}{{/each}}`. But this won't give you the `,` yet. There would be workarounds with some `{{#if}}`s to also get the commas right - on template side. But I would encourage you to either use a helper or create a cp in that component.

Comment: if you change the mut to an action in you your controller or wrapper component you can use arrayVariable.joins(', ') https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join What you're attempting to do isn't something that should be done in a template.

Comment: What do you mean with 'template side'? Really directly in the `.hbs` file only, or would it be okay to use a computed property in your controller/component `.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is with an action. however you *can* do it only with an template and a custom helper.

So what I would do is a simple action:

```
mutOwners(experiment, owners) {
  experiment.set('owners', owners.join(','));
}
```

and then just use it in the template, by replacing this:

```
onchange=(action (mut experiment.owners))
```

with this:

```
onchange=(action 'mutOwners' experiment)
```